# How to get rows count of rowset in OLE DB

Tags: oledb, rowcount, oledbcommand

How is possible to get rows count of rowset in OLE DB? I have filled RowSet using CCommand and CAccessor and now I dont know how to get rows count. 
I can go through all rows using MoveNext() but it does not seem efective.
Thanks